# How do I import a form from Adobe Forms Central?

Tags: cognito-forms

How do I import a form from Adobe Forms Central?

Answer (score 1):

You can import your Adobe FormsCentral forms into [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) here: https://www.cognitoforms.com/l/Adobe-FormsCentral-Alternative

From this page you can:

1. Instantly preview your form in Cognito Forms by entering a url to one of your Adobe forms
2. Bulk import one or more forms directly into either a new or existing Cognito Forms account

[image]

Also, we have a handy FAQ for those converting from FormsCentral:
http://help.cognitoforms.com/faqs-for-adobe-formscentral-users

Help documentation on how to import your forms:
http://blog.cognitoforms.com/import-your-web-forms-from-adobe-formscentral

And a detailed feature comparison to help you decide if Cognito Forms is the right alternative for you:
http://blog.cognitoforms.com/feature-comparison-adobe-formscentral